# area chart with mysql in java fxml

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea, javafx

I am trying to create Area chart with MySQL Database in Intellij Platform.
I want to display Atmospheric data in Area chart from mysql database.
This is Area chart method Code:

```
AreaChart areaChart;
public void contAreaTabM(Event event) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, ClassCastException {

    //ObservableList<XYChart.Series<Integer, Double>> answer = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    XYChart.Series<Integer, Double> temperature = new XYChart.Series<>();
    XYChart.Series<Integer, Double> pressure = new XYChart.Series<>();
    XYChart.Series<Integer, Double> humidity = new XYChart.Series<>();
    temperature.setName("Temperature");
    pressure.setName("Pressure");
    humidity.setName("Humidity");

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test","root","");
    //PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement("Select Username, Password from login where username = ?");
    String query = "Select Year_1, Temperature, Pressure, Humidity FROM atomdata";
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

    //pst.setString(1, editUsername.getText());
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    while(rs.next()) {
            temperature.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(rs.getInt("Year_1"), rs.getDouble("Temperature")));
            pressure.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(rs.getInt("Year_1"), rs.getDouble("Pressure")));
            humidity.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(rs.getInt("Year_1"), rs.getDouble("Humidity")));
    }
    //answer.addAll(Temperature, Pressure, Humidity);
    areaChart.getData().addAll(temperature, pressure, humidity);
}
```

Please help me to solve this query.
when I run Application it shows this error

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
at javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis.calculateRequiredSize(CategoryAxis.java:378)
at javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis.autoRange(CategoryAxis.java:363)
at javafx.scene.chart.Axis.computePrefHeight(Axis.java:577)
at javafx.scene.Parent.prefHeight(Parent.java:924)
at javafx.scene.layout.Region.prefHeight(Region.java:1435)
at javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.layoutChartChildren(XYChart.java:687)
at javafx.scene.chart.Chart$1.layoutChildren(Chart.java:94)
at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1076)
at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1082)
at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1082)
at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1082)
at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1082)
at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1082)
at javafx.scene.Scene.doLayoutPass(Scene.java:552)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2397)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$30(Toolkit.java:314)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit$$Lambda$151/250776792.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:313)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:340)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:525)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:505)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$400(QuantumToolkit.java:334)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit$$Lambda$42/1119034921.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(WinApplication.java:101)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$38/636526176.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Please add line numbers, or highlight line which causes error.

Comment: There is no highlight line. which shows error

Answer (score 0):

first of all, it would be better to add the complete code snippet to better understand your problem.

according to your exception:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
at javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis.calculateRequiredSize(CategoryAxis.java:378)
at javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis.autoRange(CategoryAxis.java:363)
at javafx.scene.chart.Axis.computePrefHeight(Axis.java:577)
```

you are using CategoryAxis as X Axis for your chart which is used for String representation, and you are trying to add integer value to it thus you have cast exception.

probably what you need to do, is to parse your rs.getInt("Year_1") to a String according to your logic.

you can follow Oracle chart tutorial examples:
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/line-chart.htm

Comment: Thanx For your suggestion. I have Changed Integer to String and Code works perfectly.